# LessCss - Can the &:extend function be nested?

Tags: css, less

I've recently come across the Less &:extend function.

What I would like to do is be able to nest two or more extends - in other words extend to a class that itself extends to another.

Having tested it, it seems that it either does not work, or I'm going about it the wrong way. The first extend is extended and the second nested extend isn't.

I've looked on the Less site, some authority blogs and cannot find any reference to whether or not it is possible.

Here's an example:

```
.clearfix
{
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}

.inline-list
{
    &:extend(.clearfix all);

    > li {
        float:left;
    }
}

.test
{
    &:extend(.inline-list all);
    // clearfix is not extended to test
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but for me it's a little unclear what you want to achieve. Can you show the result you want to achieve?(in css)

Comment: I've added an example - as .inline-list inherits .clearfix, I would expect this relationship to be maintained when I extend to .inline-list from .test. This is not the case. .test extends to .inline-list but not .clearfix - therefore the .inlinelist does not work, lacking the .clearfix

Comment: What Less version do you use? Your example works in 2.3-2.4 just fine (in prev. versions there're several `extend` bugs/issues that may prevent that).

Comment: @seven-phases-max - ah, I suspect that to be the case then because I'm running dotless and from what I've read, it lags behind somewhat.

Comment: @dotnetnoob: Yes. As per the official site, it seems like dotless still has the features of Less 1.3.0 (which is quite a long way back). I tested your code in Less 1.7.5 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I dumped dotless for ServiceStack Bundler. This gives me all the latest features of Less. IMHO I would stay clear of dotless as it is not being maintained regularly enough to be considered as an option.

Answer (score 0):

`.test{ .inline-list; }` Is that what you want, or i'm still getting it wrong? 
 You can easily make a class inherit from another class like this `.class{ .anotherClass; .andYetAnotherClass; }`

Comment: If I use .clearfix as a mixin for .inline-list it works in that I extend to .inline-list and get the built in .clearfix., with extend this relationship is not maintained.